# ServiceStack doesn’t work with one word in the path in RouteAttribute, but works with two

Tags: .net

we have next problem in our code:
We have web application which uses ASP.NET Web Forms framework. And in the Areas we have API area. This uses ASP.NET MVC framework and we want to work with Api using ServiceStack. But our ServiceStack doesn’t work with one word in the path in RouteAttribute, but works with two.

For example:

1)This variant doesn’t work

localhost/api/hello

```
[Route("/hello" )]
public class HelloWorld : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
}
```

2)This variant works

localhost/api/hello/world

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}") ]
public class HelloWorld : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
}
```

3)In Web.config we have location path , which set that  by localhost/api url will work ServiceStack.Factory.

```
 <location path="webship/api">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"
         preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When our application comes in first option **(localhost/api/hello)** we take **404 Error**

Guys, Please help to resolve this problem )

Answer (score 0):

See the docs for [Running ServiceStack side-by-side with MVC](http://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework), i.e. if you want ServiceStack to be hosted at `/api` your Web.config should look like:

```
<location path="api">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" 
         type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" 
         verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" 
         resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

And you'll also need to set the `HandlerFactoryPath` in your AppHost Configure():

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
}
```